# Animation of moving arraylist objects

Tags: java, for-loop, animation, arraylist, graphics

I am creating an animation. Car moves and waves are being created around it. Waves are ArrayList objects. I want the waves to look like this:

[image]

I want them to be closer to each other at the front of car, and far from each other at the back.

[image]

With this code waves look like this:

(they are closer to each other at the back, not at the front)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    CarParametrs  pa = pAuto;
    pa.xPos += pa.velX;

    HumanParametrs pc = pHuman;
    pc.xPos += pc.velX;
    synchronized (waves) {
        for (WaveParameters w : waves) {
            if(pa.velX==0 && pc.velX==0)
            {
                w.xPos = pa.xPos+50;
                w.height+=20; 
                w.width+=20; 
                w.yPos-=20/5 ; 
            }
            else{
            w.xPos = pa.xPos+50;
            w.height+=pa.velX; 
            w.width+=pa.velX; 
            for (WaveParameters ww : waves) {
                ww.xPos-=5; //for ww.xPos +5; they appear not next to each other
                ww.width+=1;

            }

            w.yPos-=pa.velX/5 ; 
            }
        }
    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->repaint());

}
```

Could you please tell me, how to solve this problem?
Whole class looks like this:

```
public class PanelAnimation extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

public PanelAnimation(ResourceBundle bundle) {
    super();
    resourceBundle = bundle;

    try {                
        imageBackground = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.png"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }    
}
CarParametrs pAuto = new CarParametrs();
HumanParametrs pHuman = new HumanParametrs() ;
ArrayList<WaveParameters> waves = new ArrayList<WaveParameters>();
Timer t = new Timer(60,this);
Timer draw; 
public void addAuto(){
    CarParametrs ap = new CarParametrs();
    ap.setX(0);
    pAuto = ap;
}
public void addHuman(){
    HumanParametrs acz = new HumanParametrs();
    acz.setX(0);
    pHuman = acz;
}

public void animationStart() {
    t.start();
}

public void animationStop() {
    t.stop();
}
public void addTimerAddingWaves(){
    if(draw==null) {
        draw= new Timer(300, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    WaveParameters wave = new WaveParameters(); 
                    waves.add(wave); 

                }
            });

        draw.start();
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0, null);
    pAuto.paint(g);
    pHuman.paint(g);
    synchronized (waves) {
        for (WaveParameters w : waves) {
            w.paint(g);
        }
    }   
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
    CarParametrs  pa = pAuto;
    pa.xPos += pa.velX;

    HumanParametrs pc = pHuman;
    pc.xPos += pc.velX;
    synchronized (waves) {
        for (WaveParameters w : waves) {
            if(pa.velX==0 && pc.velX==0)
            {
                w.xPos = pa.xPos+50;
                w.height+=20; 
                w.width+=20; 
                w.yPos-=20/5 ; 
            }
            else{
            w.xPos = pa.xPos+50;
            w.height+=pa.velX; 
            w.width+=pa.velX; 
            for (WaveParameters ww : waves) {
                ww.xPos-=5;
                ww.width+=1;
            }
            w.yPos-=pa.velX/5 ; 
            }
        }
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->repaint());
}

Color colorPanelAnimation;
TitledBorder titlePanelAnimation;
ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
private BufferedImage imageBackground;

public void stopTimerAddingWaves() {
    if(draw!=null) {
        draw.stop();
        draw=null;
    }
}
```

And WaveParameters class is:

```
public class WaveParameters {

int xPos=0;
int yPos = 375;
int width=60;
int height=60;
int velX = 5 ;
private Color color = Color.white;
public int getVelX() {
    return velX;
}

public void setVelX(int velX) {
    this.velX = velX;
}

public int getX() {
    return xPos;
}

public void setX(int xPos) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
}

public int getY() {
    return xPos;
}

public void setY(int yPos) {
    this.yPos = yPos;
}

public int getWidth(){
  return width;
} 

public int getHeight(){
  return height;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
  g.setColor(getColor());
  g.drawOval(xPos,yPos,width/2,height/2);
}
```

}

Comment: Don't put image redirections. Read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First of all, the line `w.xPos = pa.xPos+50;` will reset the position of each wave (what's done inside the second loop won't take effect as `xPos` will be overridden). Second, are you sure that `pAuto` isn't modified while handling the waves position?

Comment: @SergioLema according to first - what exactly do you mean? it is true, that next waves are added around the car, but at xPos = 0 sometimes appears and than disappears new circle, that is true, but how to solve it? according to second - it is not modified

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come at when you set the x position of the wave. Let's describe it:

- First iteration: set wave1.xPos = auto.xPos + 50, then iterate over all waves decreasing 5

  - wave1.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - 5
  - wave2.xPos = -5
  - wave3.xPos = -5
  - and so on
- Second iteration: set wave2.xPos = auto.xPos + 50, then iterate over all waves decreasing 5

  - wave1.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - 10
  - wave2.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - 5
  - wave3.xPos = -10
  - and so on
- Last iteration: set waveLast.xPos = auto.xPos + 50, then iterate over all waves decreasing 5

  - wave1.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - (5 * size)
  - wave2.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - (5 * size-1)
  - wave3.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - (5 * size-2)
  - and so on
  - waveLast.xPos = auto.xPos + 50 - 5

**How to solve it?**

Use a single loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < waves.size; i++) {
  if (pa.velX == 0 && pc.velX == 0) {
    w.xPos = pa.xPos + 50;
    w.height += 20; 
    w.width += 20; 
    w.yPos -= 20/5;
  } else {
    w.xPos = pa.xPos + 50 - (5 * i);
    w.height += pa.velX; 
    w.width += pa.velX + (i + 1);
    w.yPos -= pa.velX/5; 
  }
}
```

This will make that the first wave (smallest one) more at the right, and the last wave (the biggest one) more at the left.

Comment: Actually it is still the same - in front they are far away from each other and almost at one and the same place behind the car. But they are just wider than in my code

Comment: I assume that xPos is the horizontal axis, and yPos is the vertical axis, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, did you try by setting absolute values for height, width and yPos too, instead of increasing/decreasing them at each cycle? As `w.height = pa.velX + i`, `w.width = pa.velX + i` and `w.yPos = pa.velX/5`. Same for the zero speed.

Comment: then no waves appear at all. I thought that this problem is only an issue of ` ww.xPos-=5;` because for that waves look exactly as I want, but inverted (front with back)

Comment: The first wave which is iterated, is it the smallest or the biggest?

Comment: The first one is small, and it grows, after a few miliseconds the next , small appears and grows as the first one, and so on, so first one is the biggest after all

Comment: It is an animation, where circles appear and increase their height and width  to imitate moving sound wave

Comment: I just tested the code above with some mock data, and the inner/smallest wave is the most at the right, and the outer/biggest wave is the most at the left. There is some information I don't have that prevent me to help you more (values are negatives, initial values, concurrent usages, another thread modifying the data...)

Comment: I can show you my WaveParameters class or explain again  what I exactly need to be helped with. Or a few more classes, like whole animationPanel for instance

Comment: Ok, last try: in my example, can you test with `w.xPos += pa.velX - (5 * i);` when setting the xPos?

Comment: now the circles appear at the x=0 and move further. they don't appear "in" car and grow around it, as they are supposed. I have just edited my question. maybe it could help?

Comment: Try to print into the console (or log file) the values of `WaveParameters` when entering in `actionPerformed` and when exiting. This will show you if the position of the inner wave is more to the left or right than the second inner wave. Try to print in the display the ID of the wave, to be sure that the inner wave is the first.

Comment: The iteration does not work for waves, because they are WaveParameters objects, or I don't know how to do it properly. Thank you for your time in general